# Integration test setup fails The entity ID is incorrect. Verify the ID and try again

Tags: magento2.3, integration-test

I have an existing store with a collection of existing plugins.
I'm trying to setup an integration test to test some new features, but the test doesn't get past the installation:

```
Module 'Manadev_SpecialCategories':
Installing schema...
In EavSetup.php line 296:

  [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
  The entity ID is incorrect. Verify the ID and try again.
```

I checked the code in the stack trace and I see that this plugin in it's setup script tries to select the id from `eavy_entity_type` where `entity_type_code` is `catalog_category`

But, in the testing database this table is completely empty, so the setup script fails.
Is there a way to bypass this, or trigger the magento seeders to get integration tests running smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this for now by modifying

`dev/tests/integration/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Application.php` by removing the local from the target filename where the global-config.php is copied.

```php
/**
 * Copies global configuration file from the tests folder (see 
 TESTS_GLOBAL_CONFIG_FILE)
 *
 * @return void
 */
private function copyGlobalConfigFile()
{
    $targetFile = $this->_configDir . '/config.php';
    copy($this->globalConfigFile, $targetFile);
}
```

This way Magento sees which modules I wish to disable and merges my settings into the generated config that is generated by the `setup:install` call.

Somehow Magento ignores the config.local modules settings that get ignored.

By copying it this way, the modules I set up to be ignored in config-global.php get actually ignored during the setup:install process, allowing me a mean and lean testing environment for my module.

I am open for better ways to resolve this so I can disable modules I don't need in configuration.